# Summarization with Huggingface: How to generate one word at a time?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, summarization, huggingface

I am using a DistilBART for abstractive summarization. The method [`generate()`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.19.2/en/main_classes/text_generation#transformers.generation_utils.GenerationMixin.generate) is very straightforward to use. However, it returns complete, finished summaries. **What I want is, at each step, access the logits to then get the list of next-word candidates and choose based on my own criteria.** Once chosen, continue with the next word and so on until the EOS token is produced.

I am aware that I can access the logits by doing `model(**input).logits[:, -1, :]`, but here the input would be the whole (encoded) text, so what would exactly these logits correspond with? The first generated token? The last?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/control-encoderdecodermodel-to-generate-tokens-step-by-step/1756/6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For future reference, **here is how it can be done** (*note:* this is specific to encoder-decoder models, like BART):

**1. Initialization**

```py
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

# Load model
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("sshleifer/distilbart-xsum-1-1")
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("sshleifer/distilbart-xsum-1-1")

text = "..."

# Tokenize text
batch = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt")
```

**2. Example 1: Summary generation with *greedy decoding* (no cache)**

```py
generated_sequence = torch.tensor([[tokenizer.sep_token_id]])  # initial token

# Generation loop
while True:
    with torch.no_grad():
        output = model(input_ids=batch["input_ids"], decoder_input_ids=generated_sequence)
    next_token_logits = output.logits[:, -1, :]
    next_token_scores = next_token_logits.softmax(dim=-1)

    # Take token with highest probability
    next_token = next_token_scores.argmax().unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)

    # Append token to generated sequence
    generated_sequence = torch.cat((generated_sequence, next_token), dim=1)
    # Stop if EOS token generated
    if (generated_sequence.squeeze()[-1] == tokenizer.eos_token_id):
        break

summary = tokenizer.batch_decode(generated_sequence, skip_special_tokens=True)
```

**3. Example 2: Summary generation with *top-k, top-p sampling & temperature* (no cache)**

```py
from transformers.generation_utils import top_k_top_p_filtering

temperature = 0.7
generated_sequence = torch.tensor([[tokenizer.sep_token_id]])  # initial token

# Generation loop
while True:
    with torch.no_grad():
        output = model(input_ids=batch["input_ids"], decoder_input_ids=generated_sequence)
    logits = output.logits[:, -1, :] / temperature  # apply temperature
    filtered_logits = top_k_top_p_filtering(logits=logits, top_k=4, top_p=0.7)
    probabilities = filtered_logits.softmax(dim=-1)

    # Sample next token
    next_token = torch.multinomial(probabilities, 1)

    # Append token to generated sequence
    generated_sequence = torch.cat((generated_sequence, next_token), dim=1)
    # Stop if EOS token generated
    if (generated_sequence.squeeze()[-1] == tokenizer.eos_token_id):
        break

summary = tokenizer.batch_decode(generated_sequence, skip_special_tokens=True)
```

(Other [generating strategies](https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-generate) would be analogous).

**4. Using cache**

Since the input to the encoder (i.e., the text to be summarized) is always the same, we can cache it to greatly speed up the generation.

```py
generated_sequence = torch.tensor([[tokenizer.sep_token_id]])  # initial token
input_ids = batch["input_ids"]
past_key_values = None

with torch.no_grad():
    output = model(
        input_ids=input_ids,
        decoder_input_ids=generated_sequence,
        past_key_values=past_key_values
    )
    
encoder_outputs=output.encoder_last_hidden_state

# Generation loop
while True:
    # From here on, use cached attention
    past_key_values = output.past_key_values
    next_token_logits = output.logits[:, -1, :]
    next_token_scores = next_token_logits.softmax(dim=-1)
    next_token = next_token_scores.argmax().unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)  # greedy decoding
    generated_sequence = torch.cat((generated_sequence, next_token), dim=1)
    # Stop if EOS token generated
    if (generated_sequence.squeeze()[-1] == tokenizer.eos_token_id):
        break
    with torch.no_grad():
        output = model(
            decoder_input_ids=torch.tensor([[generated_sequence.squeeze()[-1]]]),
            past_key_values=past_key_values,
            encoder_outputs=encoder_outputs
        )

summary = tokenizer.batch_decode(generated_sequence, skip_special_tokens=True)
```

Comment: Missing "temperature = 0.7"?

Comment: @TomJ sorry for the late reply! I edited it initializing the temperature. Thanks!